# How to use fetch within a for-loop, wait for results and then console.log it

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

i have this problem: i want to make multiple fetch calls within a for-loop. The number of calls depend on the user input (in my example i have three). How can i make it loop through all the fetch requests and then console.log the number off calls?

function getPosts(){

```
  let url = ["https://www.freecodecamp.org", "https://www.test.de/, http://www.test2.com"];
  let array = new Array;

  for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
    console.log(url[i]);
    fetch(url[i])
    .then(res => {return res.text(); })
    .then(res => {
            let reg = /\<meta name="description" content\=\"(.+?)\"/;
            res = res.match(reg);
            array.push(res);
            console.log(res);
          }
    )
    .catch(status, err => {return console.log(status, err);})
  }
  console.log (array.length);
  }
```

It console.logs 0 instead of 3, cause it doesn't wait for all the promises to be resolved. How can i make it to console.log 3?
If you know a solution, please help me out.

Answer (score 16):

You can't call console.log(array.length) until *after* the promises are all done.  So why not something like this?

```
let url = ["https://www.freecodecamp.org", "https://www.test.de/, http://www.test2.com"];
  let array = new Array;
  var fetches = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
    console.log(url[i]);
    fetches.push(
      fetch(url[i])
      .then(res => {return res.text(); })
      .then(res => {
            let reg = /\<meta name="description" content\=\"(.+?)\"/;
            res = res.match(reg);
            array.push(res);
            console.log(res);
          }
      )
      .catch(status, err => {return console.log(status, err);})
    );
  }
  Promise.all(fetches).then(function() {
    console.log (array.length);
  });
  }
```

Promise.all waits for all the fetches to finish, THEN it'll print the #.

Comment: thanks for the idea. it does work, but only if all the fetch requests are succesfully resolved...do you know how i can have the console.log, if one of the fetch requests fail?

Comment: Promise.all(fetches).then(function() {
    console.log (array.length);
  }).catch(function(e){ todo: log error e}) ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use async/await with try/catch:

```js
async function getPosts(){
  let array = [];
  let url = ["https://www.freecodecamp.org", "https://www.test.de/", "http://www.test2.com"];
  let reg = /\<meta name="description" content\=\"(.+?)\"/;
  for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++)   {
    console.log('fetching',url[i]);
    try {
      let p1 = await fetch(url[i]);
      let p2 = await p1.text();
      let res = p2.match(reg);
      array.push(res);
      console.log('adding',res);
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  };
  console.log ('length',array.length);
};

getPosts().then(()=>{console.log('done')});
```

Comment: I think the idea is not to wait for fetch to finish before moving next in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can try chaining your promises, Try the following:

```js
function getPosts(){

  let url = ["https://www.freecodecamp.org", "https://www.test.de/, http://www.test2.com"];
  let array = new Array;
  var promise = Promise.resolve();
  for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
    console.log(url[i]);
    promise = promise.then(fetch(url[i]))
    .then(res => {return res.text(); })
    .then(res => {
            let reg = /\<meta name="description" content\=\"(.+?)\"/;
            res = res.match(reg);
            array.push(res);
            console.log(res);
          }
    )
    .catch(status, err => {return console.log(status, err);})
  }
  promise.then(function(response){
    console.log (array.length);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use promise, A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers with an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason. This lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead of immediately returning the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise to supply the value at some point in the future.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
let url = ["https://www.freecodecamp.org", "https://www.test.de/, http://www.test2.com"];
let array = new Array;
function get(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => { return res.text(); })
      .then(res => {
        let reg = /\<meta name="description" content\=\"(.+?)\"/;
        res = res.match(reg);
        resolve(res)
        //console.log(res);
      }
      )
      .catch(err => { reject(err) })
  });
}
async function result() {
  for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
    const value = await get(url[i]);
    array.push(value)

  }
  console.log(array.length)
}

result()
```

==> array.length = 2,

Comment: thanks for the input. How would i write that promise

Answer (score 0):

You can use async await ( async: function, await: operator ). Await operator simply wait for the promise to be resolved. First promise will be resolved then it will move to another one. Also, if it finds error in any fetch, it will catch the error right away.