# What is the 'correct way' of using fetch() within a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, asynchronous, promise

I'm having trouble understanding where my for loop needs to go if I'm fetching with it. I have code that is dependent on all the promises being resolved and JSON data being saved to `testarray`

I have created a variety of attempts, but they don't solve my problem. One is to for loop the call to a function which has a promise within it.

```
function getData() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            fetch(url[i])
                .then((resp) => resp.json())
                .then(function (data) {
                    buffer = data;
                    resolve();
                });
        });
}

for (i = 0; i <2; i++){
    getData().then(function(){
    testarray.push(buffer);
    //do stuff with testarray
    })
    
}
```

but this doesn't work because I cant use the data that is pushed on `testarray`, unless its in the for loop block.

If I put the for loop around the promise or around the fetch, I have a similar problem.

So my question is. If you use a for loop to fetch a variety of JSONs with an API call, how do you use the data outside the for loop? The actions I need for the data require all of it to be done.

I'm confused because I feel like Javascript is forcing me to put the action or code associated with the data where my comment is. Is this normal?

Comment: consider using async-await and pass `i` to `getData`

Comment: Promise all or await /async

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012819/how-to-use-fetch-within-a-for-loop-wait-for-results-and-then-console-log-it)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will be using async await. Big thanks to @mpgbk for the link.

Comment: Start by avoiding the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1):

You have the `Promise.all` API to tackle your problem. This method will execute all the promises passed to it and will no resolve until all of them its ok.

This, together with `async/await`, could be a great solution for your problem:

```js
async function forFetch(){
    let urls = [/* your urls */], fetches = [];

    for(let url of urls){ 
        fetches.push(fetch(url));
    }
    
    let results = await Promise.all(fetches);
    return results; //do whatever you want with your results like converting them to json.
}
```