# How to wait for secondary fetched result with JavaScript when the result of a primary fetch is a specific value within a loop?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, async-await, fetch-api

Within a `timer` called javascript `function` I need update a UI using several json API calls.
It's an energy meter which stores the actual consumed phase power in 3 different registers. Except for negative values (energy by solar panels), this returned energy is stored in 3 other registers (as a positive value). `If` phase power is 0, I need need to fetch the alternate phase power register.

```
Loop 3 times
  Fetch A at api1
  If A=0 Then
    Fetch A at api2
  Display A
  Display min(A)
  Display max(A)
  Display trend
  Even more display stuff I don't want to duplicate
```

I manage to fetch the value, however can't get the alternative fetched value to survive below the `fetch` block. Display A = 0 when fetching api2 (which returns not 0).

I tried `async` and `await`, like [Javascript - How to use fetch inside a for loop and wait for results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66715695/javascript-how-to-use-fetch-inside-a-for-loop-and-wait-for-results). Thus change 2 lines in the code below:

```
async function update()
…
                        await fetch(APIGW+"v1/sm/fields/power_returned_l"+myPhase)
```

That results in:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators
Uncaught ReferenceError: update is not defined
```

How to make the bottom `document.getElementById` (and loads of UI stuff below) to wait for the 2nd level (not the 2nd loop) fetch when this `if (nvKW == 0 )` block is executed?

```
function update()
{
    var phase;
    for( let phase = 1 ; phase <= PHASES ; phase++ )
    {
        fetch(APIGW+"v1/sm/fields/power_delivered_l"+phase)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => 
          {
            for( let j in json.fields ){
                if (json.fields[j].name.startsWith("power_delivered_l"))
                {
                    myPhase = Number(json.fields[j].name.replace('power_delivered_l',''));

                    let nvKW=Number(json.fields[j].value)
                    if (nvKW == 0 ) // check if power is generated
                    {
                        fetch(APIGW+"v1/sm/fields/power_returned_l"+myPhase)
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(json2 => 
                          {
                            for( let jr in json2.fields ){
                                if (json2.fields[jr].name.startsWith("power_returned_l"))
                                {
                                    let nvKW=-1*Number(json2.fields[jr].value)
                                    console.log(json2.fields[jr].name+" = "+ nvKW.toString()) // here nvKW contains a value
                                }
                            }
                          }
                        );
                    }

                    console.log("nvKW = "+ nvKW.toString()) // 1st level fetch = 0 and 2nd level fetch != 0 then nvKW is still 0 here, where I need the value from the 2nd level fetch
                    document.getElementById(json.fields[j].name).innerHTML = nvKW.toFixed(1);
                    // a lot more ui stuff is done below
```

Comment: Then... you can put `document.getElementById(json.fields[j].name).innerHTML = nvKW.toFixed(1);` inside the `.then(json2 => {})` code block

Comment: @Pipe I can't put `document.getElementById(json.fields[j].name).innerHTML = nvKW.toFixed(1);` inside the `.then(json2 => {})` because all the UI stuff should also get executed when `nvKW != 0 `. In such a case that whole `if(){}` code block is skipped over.

Comment: Using `await` for the second `fetch` (inside the `if` block) would work, can you show us *how* you tried to use it? Alternatively, see [if-else flow in promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26600424/1048572). Notice the outer (first) `fetch` and the loop around it are irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: @Bergi I have inserted my `async`  `await` try and the errrors in return, in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.then()` syntax on a conditional promise:

```
json => {
    const field = getFieldByName(json, "power_delivered_l");
    const myPhase = field.name.replace('power_delivered_l','');
    (field.value == 0 // check if power is generated
      ? fetch(APIGW+"v1/sm/fields/power_returned_l"+myPhase)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json2 => getFieldByName(json2, "power_returned_l", -1))
      : Promise.resolve(field)
    ).then(({name, value: nvKW}) => {
         console.log(`${name} = ${nvKW}`)
         document.getElementById(json.fields[j].name).innerHTML = nvKW.toFixed(1);
         // a lot more ui stuff is done below
    });
}
```

Using `async`/`await`:

```
async json => {
    let field = getFieldByName(json, "power_delivered_l");
    if (field.value == 0) // check if power is generated
        const myPhase = field.name.replace('power_delivered_l','');
        const response = await fetch(APIGW+"v1/sm/fields/power_returned_l"+myPhase);
        const json2 = await response.json())
        field = getFieldByName(json2, "power_returned_l", -1))
    }
    const {name, value: nvKW} = field;
     console.log(`${name} = ${nvKW}`)
     document.getElementById(json.fields[j].name).innerHTML = nvKW.toFixed(1);
     // a lot more ui stuff is done below
}
```

Both using a helper function

```
function getFieldByName(json, prefix, factor = 1) {
    for (const field of json.fields) {
        if (field.name.startsWith(prefix)) {
             return {
                 name: field.name,
                 value: factor * Number(field.value)
             };
        }
    }
    throw new Error(`Did not find field '${prefix}' in the JSON`);
}
```

Comment: I opted for the `.then()` construct. During daytime (with negative power values) this runs ok. Still needs testing during night time.

Answer (score 0):

Then use an else:

```
function updateUIwithA(A){
   //Do whatever you need to update UI from A
   //document.getElementById("fieldNameForDisplayAValue").innerHTML = getValue(A);
   //document.getElementById("fieldNameForDisplayAMin").innerHTML = getMin(A);
   //document.getElementById("fieldNameForDisplayAMax").innerHTML = getMax(A);
   //document.getElementById("fieldNameForDisplayAverage").innerHTML = getAverage(A);
}


                    ...
                    let nvKW=Number(json.fields[j].value)
                    if (nvKW == 0 ) // check if power is generated
                    {
                        //First power is 0, then fetch the second power
                        fetch(APIGW+"v1/sm/fields/power_returned_l"+myPhase)
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(json2 => 
                          {
                            for( let jr in json2.fields ){
                                if (json2.fields[jr].name.startsWith("power_returned_l"))
                                {
                                    //Show second power
                                    let nvKW2=-1*Number(json2.fields[jr].value)
                                    console.log(json2.fields[jr].name+" = "+ nvKW.toString()) // here nvKW contains a value
                                    updateUIwithA(json2);
                                }
                            }
                          }
                        );
                    } else {
                       //First power is not 0, so show the current value and ignore second fetch
                       updateUIwithA(json);
                    }
```

Comment: Beside displaying the value also min/max/etcetera has to be checked and displayed. In such a case all UI code needs duplication. Maybe I can wrap it in a function. Still less ideal.

Comment: Then... in your pseudo code, you only have values called A... in my example, A is json or a is json2 (when the first one is equal to 0)... Then you can do a function to update All your UI with that value.. no need to repeat code... I will update my code.

Comment: Pipe thank you for your effort. I still prefer the approach from Bergi.